# number of instructions in foo.class java file

Tags: java, .class-file

I have binary of a java program say foo.class. Is it possible that I count the number of instructions in that class file ? or do I have to have the source code to count the number of instructions.

Comment: What do you consider to be "an instruction"? You can always count bytecodes (or a subset thereof).

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [disassemble](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/11/16/decompiling-java-class/) the class using [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html). The **-c** option

> ...prints out disassembled code, i.e., the instructions that comprise the
>   Java bytecodes, for each of the methods in the class. These are
>   documented in the Java Virtual Machine Specification